# No module named 'info' on fresh Python 3 installation

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, scikits

I did a fresh python3 installation on OSX via homebrew:

```
brew install python3
```

Then I created a virtual environment for my project and installed `scipy` and `scikits.samplerate`:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 pythen_env 
pip install scipy
pip install scikits.samplerate
```

However, when I try to import a function from `scikits.samplerate`, I get the following error:

```
>>> from scikits.samplerate import resample
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/my/project/path/pythen_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scikits/samplerate/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from info import __doc__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'info'
```

Info happens to be the first module from the package itself that is imported in `__init__.py`.

Strangely, the module `info.py` exists in `/my/project/path/pythen_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scikits/samplerate/`:

```
ls /my/project/path/pythen_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scikits/samplerate/
__init__.py    setup.py        tests        __pycache__
info.py        setuphelp.py    version.py
```

The error also happens when I try the same without `virtualenv`, as well as for other packages. How could I start to debug this issue?

Comment: You appear to be using a version of that module for Python 2.x; in 3.x, that should be `from .info ...`

Comment: This problem does not occur in Python 2.7.

Comment: I can not switch to Python 2.7 due to a library dependency. How could I make sure that pip installs the correct version? I'd expect pip3 to fetch packages for Python 3 only, but the same error happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the package [`scikits.samplerate`](https://github.com/cournape/samplerate) does not support Python 3.X (see [issue](https://github.com/cournape/samplerate/issues/8)). However, there is [a fork which supports Python 3.X](https://github.com/gregorias/samplerate). You can install it via

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/gregorias/samplerate.git
```

As always: people can make anything they like in repositories. I did not check which changes gregorias made.

Answer (score 2):

the git version does support py3

https://github.com/cournape/samplerate

(merged the PR from @gregorias)

I should find the time and procedure to update pypi too...